# Which option to choose in the advanced formatting?

Tags: system-installation, format

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Netbook Asus Eeepc-900 from bootable USB. When I see partitions screen I just wanna one single partition and then install Ubuntu, but has some many options that I don't know which choose.

Here are the options:
1 [image: First part]
2 [image: Second part]
3 [image: Option from menu]

Well, I would leave only a partition with Ubuntu installed. 
Grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two hard disks (one 4GB and one 16GB), and the 16GB disk has [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) set up on it.
So the structure would be like this:

```
NAME
sda
├─sda1
├─sda5
sdb
├─sdb1
└─sdb5
  └─ubuntu--vg
    └─ubuntu--vg-root
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

The LVM volumes (the ones starting with `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-`) are actually contained in `/dev/sdb5`. (You can use the `lsblk` command to find out.)

So you can install Ubuntu in `ubuntu--vg-root` (use it for `/`). The other partitions can be left alone.

Comment: Which is marked as `ext4`?

Comment: @FilipeManuel ah, yes.

Comment: When I click on checkbox open a box with many options: `Ext4 journaling file system, Ext3 journaling file system, Ext2 journaling file system, btrfs journaling file system, JFS journaling file system, XFS journaling file system, FAT16 file system, FAT32 file system, swap area, physical volume for encription and do not use the partition`

Comment: @FilipeManuel pick Ext4 and mount it at `/`.

Comment: Ok, just one more question... Need to check `Format the partition: `?

Comment: @FilipeManuel Yes, if you already had Ubuntu installed on it and want to overwrite it.

Comment: Ok, I'll proceed with the installation. Not yet give +1 because might have more questions, if not, give the upvote! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17966/discussion-between-filipe-manuel-and-muru).